# Question related to Hermitian Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If A is a Hermitian matrix of order n-cross-n. Then show that the rank of A is equal to the number of nonzero eigen values of A,but this is not generally true for non- Hermitian matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is a Hermitian matrix, it is self-adjoint, and hence normal.  By the spectral theorem for normal operators, there is an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors for $A$ which diagonalizes $A$.  It should now be clear that the rank of $A$ is precisely the number of nonzero eigenvalues along the diagonal of the diagonalized matrix.